# How to Load items in comobox inside a datagrid Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

App: Silvelight 4 Business app template + RIA services + C#.
I combined the aspnet membership db into my database.
I'm able to register user, login and logout.

I need to be able to assign users roles from the application/client-side UI.
There are 3 roles in the aspnet membership i created using the config tool.

I created an extra table "UserAccess" that has the **UserId** from aspnet_Users table as **FK**,the **RoleID** from aspnet_Roles table as **FK** and **Startdate as PK**.

Entities generated using ADO.net Entity data model.
Domain service class generated usign these entities.

In the service class file i added "include" keyword to

```
UserAccesses.Include("aspnet_Users").Include("aspnet_Roles");
```

In metadata file

```
[Include]
public aspnet_Roles aspnet_Roles { get; set; }
[Include]
public aspnet_Users aspnet_Users { get; set; }
```

since I had navigation properties on them.

I used the domain datasource(RIA controls) and dragged the datagrid onto my page.
I set the Roles to combobox.
I was successfully able to load the table,including the username and the rolename from the other tables.
By default everything is showing-up correctly.

```
<ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=aspnet_Roles.RoleName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

But when I click on the cell/combobox i want to load the 3 available roles so that the user can edit/choose and submit changes? How can I achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load aspnet_Roles table rows and bind it to ComboBox. You need to store it in a seperate property and Bind it like this

```
ItemSource={Binding Path=Roles, Source={StaticResource YourViewModel}}"
```

Cheers!
Vinod